# How can I use block variables from for loops?

Tags: ruby

I am trying to use block variables `row` and `col` from `for` loops, and I'm getting `no implicit conversion of Array into Integer` error.

```
@arr.each do |row|
  row.each do |col|
    if (col == 1)
      if (row != 0)
        # figure out how to use row and col variables
        # example @arr[row][col] = 1
      end
    end
  end
end
end
```

Any help would be appreciated. I figured I could just use them like I can in other languages and regular `for` loops.

Comment: Doesn't this cause syntax error? What is `@arr`?

Comment: why you compare an array and a fix number? What are you trying to accomplish by doing `row != 0`?

Answer (score 1):

> I figured you could just use them like you can in other languages and
>   regular for loops..

Yep, you can:

```
@arr = [
  [10, 11, 12],
  [20, 21, 22],
  [30, 31, 32],
]


@arr.each do |row|
  row.each do |col|
    p row
    puts col
    puts '-' * 10
  end
end


--output:--
[10, 11, 12]
10
----------
[10, 11, 12]
11
----------
[10, 11, 12]
12
----------
[20, 21, 22]
20
----------
[20, 21, 22]
21
----------
[20, 21, 22]
22
----------
[30, 31, 32]
30
----------
[30, 31, 32]
31
----------
[30, 31, 32]
32
----------
```

You can do something like this:

```
@arr = [
  [10],
  [20, 21],
  [30, 31, 32],
]

@arr.each do |row|
  row.size.times do |col_num|
    row[col_num] = 0
  end
end

p @arr

--output:--
[[0], [0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]
```

Or, if you actually need each row and column index:

```
@arr = [
  [10],
  [20, 21],
  [30, 31, 32],
]

@arr.each_with_index do |row, row_num|
  row.size.times do |col_num|
    row[col_num] = row_num + col_num
  end
end

p @arr


--output:--
[[0], [1, 2], [2, 3, 4]]
```

By the way, indenting is 2 spaces in ruby--not 4.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand `row` is an array (because you iterate through it), not integer, so there is no sense to do something like `@arr[row]`. `[][[]]` will give the same error. And so it's strange to compare an array with an integer (`row != 0`).

When using iterator `each` in ruby the variable thrown in a block is the element of an array, not the index of the element. If you want to use indexes you could use `each_with_index`.